# Selenium Java variables access

Tags: java, selenium

I need to know a way to access variables of a method from a class in other methods or other class.

example below: i have put all locators of a registration page in one method elements() and then i am trying to use the identifiers e1 in the main method of the same class A and in other class B i have created a object reference of Class A and then trying the same. its not working and i need to know the correct way here.

```
public class test3 {

     public void elements(){

     By e1=By.id("at-i");
     By e2=By.xpath("//td/td[2]");

    }

     public static void main (String args[])
     {

     WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://testwebsite.com");
     WebElement a1=driver.findelement(e1);

     }
    }

    class b{

     public static void main (String args[]) {

         test3 x=new test3();

         Webelement a2=x.driver.findelement(e2);

     }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access variable from another class in other methods or class. Variables defined inside a method are local to that method.

If you want to share variables between methods, then you'll need to specify them as member variables of the class (also we don't use `main` method with selenium).

In your case I'd suggest you to learn about [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/selenium.html) framework.

Answer (score 0):

Variable E1 and E2 have a local scope to `elements()` method only.

You have to declare the variables globally to access them anywhere withing the Class.

**Hint**: Declare variables outside `elements()`method but inside `test3` Class.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out. Hope below the code will help you.

package example;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class A {
    public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public By elements() {
        By e2 = By.xpath("//td/td[2]");
        return e2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A conA = new A();
        driver.get("http://testwebsite.com");
        WebElement a1 = driver.findElement(conA.elements());
        a1.sendKeys("hello");
    }
}

class B1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        A x = new A();

        WebElement b1 = x.driver.findElement(x.elements());
    }
}
```